# Great projects, works, people in intersection of programming and art/music?

Tags: flash, animation

In a recent question I was introduced to the work of [André Michelle](http://lab.andre-michelle.com/), which blew me away. What other great people or works do you know in the fields of art and music? As someone with a love for math/programming and art/music I'd love to know more about people using sophisticated (or not so sophisticated) techniques to produce creative things. The software used can be anything from Max/MSP, Flash to simple C code or Assembler. Pointers to forums, blogs, newsletters and similar are very appreciated as well.

Comment: I would like to make this a community wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Demo scene" has a whole bunch of very creative procedural visual effects and music (link: http://www.pouet.net/prodlist.php?order=views ). The goal of a "demo" is to provide the most visual effects within a specific file size ( i.e. 1kb ).

Comment: I loved Chaos Theory demo by Conspiracy. http://chaostheory.conspiracy.hu/

Answer (score 5):

The processing "language" (by Ben Fry and Casey Reas) and electric sheep (the work of Scott Draves) are both well known examples.

http://processing.org/

http://community.electricsheep.org/

I should also mention the port of processing to the HTML canvas by John Resig:

http://processingjs.org/

Answer (score 4):

Princeton's Laptop Orchestra
http://plork.cs.princeton.edu/

Synthaxe drumitar
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drumitar

Hodgepodge of sources on experimental musical instruments
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_musical_instrument

Tisch's Interactive Telecommunications Program, sample projects
http://itp.nyu.edu/sigs/
Dan O'Sullivan
http://itp.nyu.edu/~dbo3/blog/

Robert Twomey strange stuff
http://roberttwomey.com/projects/

Hiroshi ISHII and tangible media
http://web.media.mit.edu/~ishii/
http://tangible.media.mit.edu/

Polynomiography
http://www.polynomiography.com/

Ken Perlin's cool stuff
http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/

Ted Selker hci stuff
http://web.media.mit.edu/~selker/teaching.htm

Natalie Jeremijenko's wacky projects, robotics
http://www.nyu.edu/projects/xdesign/

Toshio Iwai
http://www.moma.org/explore/inside_out/tag/toshio-iwai

Matt Hope
http://matthope.org/

Vestal Design
http://www.vestaldesign.com/design/

(mentioned already) Processing multimedia framework
http://processing.org/

(mentioned already) Arduino
http://hacknmod.com/hack/top-40-arduino-projects-of-the-web/

ARToolKit
http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/

Human Interface Lab
http://www.hitlabnz.org/wiki/Home#ptr35

Make magazine
http://makezine.com/

Comment: How do I give you 100 points? :)

Comment: haha i dunno!  but thanks.  just some stuff i was exposed to while studying cs.  enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

Erik Natzke comes to mind when you say "math/programming and art" http://jot.eriknatzke.com/

Answer (score 2):

One of the most [breath-taking projects](http://hacknmod.com/hack/top-40-arduino-projects-of-the-web/) I have ever seen are the ones using [Arduino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arduino). The limit is nothing but your imagination!

Answer (score 2):

Am I allowed to nominate myself?

I think [what I do](http://www.morganpackard.com) is cool, and [what my buddy Joshue Ott does](http://superdraw.intervalstudios.com) is perhaps cooler.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, I recommend reading [Gödel, Escher, Bach: An Eternal Golden Braid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0465026567) by Douglas Hofstadter. It beautifully interweaves programming, maths and AI with art, music and poetry in a wonderfully fun and interesting way.

Answer (score 0):

One good thing to search for turned out to be [Generative Art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_art).
For instance this Blog (with videos).
http://www.generatorx.no/category/generative-art/